# php can't get last element in array

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

So I hace this pdo statement:

```
   $sql = "SELECT FD_DATUM_INGEVOERD || ' ' || FT_TIJD_INGEVOERD FROM BANDZENDINGEN WHERE FD_DATUM_INGEVOERD BETWEEN '".$bt."' AND '".$et."' AND FI_GEBRUIKER1='".$uf."' AND FI_AFVOERKANAAL='".$id."'";
   $sfm = $dbh->prepare($sql);
   $sfm->execute();
```

the result looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to get the last element of this array, so I do this:

```
 $end = array_values(array_slice($array, -1))[0];
```

and this is the result:

> 2018-07-10 14:20:09.3290

As you can see this isn't the last element of the array, What am I doing wrong I tried it with the `end()` function but the result is the same. Please help.

EDIT

last items in the array is 2018-07-10 07:23:11.9510

Comment: Using array_pop() maybe?

Comment: get count of your array and do echo $array[$count];

Comment: Do you use the other data?

Comment: `end(array)` use builtin function end

Comment: *As you can see this isn't the last element of the array* We can't see because we don't know what is the last element of your array

Comment: @Anoxy [array_pop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) also removes last element of the array which is not what OP wants to do.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this?

```
function array_last($array) {
    if (count($array) < 1)
        return null;

    $keys = array_keys($array);
    return $array[$keys[sizeof($keys) - 1]];
}

var_dump(array_last($yourarray));
```

Or you can try this too.

```
$last_element=end(array_values($array));
```

Or

```
$lastKey=end(array_keys($array));
   var_dump($array[$lastkey]);
```

Or

```
var_dump($array[count($array) - 1]);
```

Comment: php has function `end`, don't invent a bicycle

Comment: Please explain why one should try any of these things - how does that solve the problem? Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from your answer

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
echo $array[count($array) - 1];
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it